# Creating a list using keys and values from a Dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Considering the following dictionary:

```
dict = {'a':2, 'b':3, 'c':1}
```

How would I create a list like the bellow, using the keys and the int values?

```
aList = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: Should the element in the list follow a certain order? Remember that dict keys are not necessarily ordered (it depends on the specific Python implementation or version).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want this in python, you can try this -

```
temp = []
for k,v in dict.items():
    temp.extend([k]*v)

print (temp)
```

Or you can use two loops -

```
temp = []
for k,v in dict.items():
   for _ in range(v):
      temp.append(k)
```

But as @LGrementieri, old python doesn't maintain the order of the keys in dictionary, so the output may be different in that case

Comment: Thank u! Im just getting started, so still grasping the syntax... I see that i had the first part correct, as i was using - for k,v in dict.items(): - , but then i was going for .append, and also (dict[k]) and getting weird stuff.. lol

Answer (score 0):

A nested list comprehension does the job.

```
[k for k, v in dict.items() for i in range(v)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A variant of [LGrementieri](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68311599/8227062) answer is

```py
[item for key, val in dict.items() for item in [key]*val]
```